# Iphone 5 error, what can i do?

Tags: iphone, error, charging

Last night my phone just turned off even though it had 53% charge. it would only turn back on if I plugged the charger in, and after being on for 40 seconds or so the phone turns off again, the screen turns green and slowly fades away. It has been absolutely fine before this and the phone will not turn back on. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem on iPhone 5 batteries.
You can check if your iPhone 5 is eligible to the replacement program at this adress : https://www.apple.com/support/iphone5-battery/other_countries.html

Comment: If your phone serial number qualifies for the battery replacement, it will also likely qualify for the button replacement too - book an appointment with a genius & get them to do both at once, pre-emptive fix.